# Drawing Spirograph designs

Tags: design-patterns, scheme, racket

I am trying to draw spirograph designs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph) in Racket. I could manage following code but it is not working:

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image
         2htdp/universe) 

(define img (rectangle 500 500 "solid" "white"))

(let* ((R 300)   ; outer circle radius
       (r 100)   ; inner circle radius
       (c 30)    ; distance of pen-tip from center of inner circle

       (l (/ c r))
       (k (/ r R))
       (imgfn
        (λ (t)
          (set! img (overlay/xy
                     img
                     (* R(+ (* (- 1 k) (cos (modulo t 360)))
                            (* l k (cos (/(* (- 1 k)
                                             (modulo t 360))
                                          k)))))
                     (* R(- (* (- 1 k) (sin (modulo t 360)))
                            (* l k (sin (/(* (- 1 k)
                                             (modulo t 360))
                                          k)))))
                     (circle 2 "solid" "blue")))
          img)))
  (animate imgfn))
```

Following diagram shows the distances that would affect the design:

[image]

Above code shows small circles for points but they do not draw a line, even if I have tried to reuse previous image. Moreover, the points are moving very fast while I would like the speed to be slowed down somewhat. Only after this we can see if it is following correct path or not.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

### Edit:

```
             (* R(+ (* (- 1 k) (cos (degrees->radians(modulo t 360))))
                    (* l k (cos (degrees->radians(/(* (- 1 k)
                                                      (modulo t 360))
                                                   k))))))
             (* R(- (* (- 1 k) (sin (degrees->radians(modulo t 360))))
                    (* l k (sin (degrees->radians(/(* (- 1 k)
                                                      (modulo t 360))
                                                 k))))))
```

After adding "degrees->radians" as suggested by @ScottHunter, following is the output:

[image]

Expected image is something similar to following (also see patterns on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph):

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: In what way(s) is it "not working"?

Comment: I have added the problems to the question above.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I have added expected output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Racket trig functions expected angles to be in radians, not degrees.

Also, you aren't using `overly/xy` properly; the following makes the code (a bit) more readable, and produces a simpler version of your expected image:

```
(define image_size 500)
(define image_radius (/ image_size 2))
(define img (rectangle image_size image_size "outline" "black"))

(let* ((R 300)   ; outer circle radius
       (r 100)   ; inner circle radius
       (c 30)    ; distance of pen-tip from center of inner circle

       (l (/ c r))
       (k (/ r R))
       (imgfn
        (λ (t)
          (let* ((rad (degrees->radians (/ (modulo t 360) 1)))
                 (scale (/ (- 1 k) k))
                 (x (* R(+ (* (- 1 k) (cos rad))
                           (* l k (cos (* scale rad))))))
                 (y (* R(- (* (- 1 k) (sin rad))
                           (* l k (sin (* scale rad)))))))
                 (set! img 
                       (overlay/xy img 
                                   (+ (- image_radius 1) x)
                                   (+ (- image_radius 1) y)
                                   (circle 2 "solid" "blue")))
          img))))
  (animate imgfn))
```

Comment: After adding "degrees->radians" to the code does lead to some pattern drawing but it is still far from the expected pattern.

Comment: I have added a gif file of output in my question.